# Fixed header issue in ipad

Tags: html, css, ipad, twitter-bootstrap

I have created responsive website in bootstrap. in that i have fixed header in top and footer in bottom.
so my issue is that when user drag page in ipad from bottom to top at the end, footer is also move same drag from top to bottom at top position header is move.

my code for header

```
header.header {
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 84px;
    z-index: 12;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

here my jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ErAshu/5r8tn/2/)

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle or URL?

Comment: Please reword your issue.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast In ipad after page complete in footer user drag incase does not footer drag from bottom. same at top position

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div around the header and the footer. For the header `<div class="navbar-static-top">`

and for the footer same but `<div class="navbar-static-bottom">`

These should be defaults in bootstrap